# Google OAuth / OpenID - use branded login page

Tags: authentication, oauth, openid, themes

I'm building a stacked identity provider (using SimpleSAMLphp).  I have successfully integrated with several OpenID and OAuth providers.  This includes Google using OpenID and now upgraded to OAuth 2.0.

The issue I'm having is that I also have a domain in Google Apps.  I'd like to integrate with Google again, but have the login page show my themed / branded login page.  This domain is not utilizing SSO, just a standard Google based login page.

I can't seem to find any options to control which page is shown ... i.e. I can only get the generic Google page to show.

Am I missing something or is this left out by design?